# Object doesn't move from one side of the screen to the other like i want it to

Tags: css, transform

So im trying to move an object from the left side of the screen to the right side, with help of css keyframes so i did this:

0%{transform: translateX(0%);}
100%{transform: translateX(100%);}

But the thing with 100% doesnt work it just moves like 1/8 of the screen to the side, instead of completely to the right side.

I hope somebody can help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`transform: translate()` translates the element relative to where it was before, not to its parent. To move relatively to the viewport, use `vw` units:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  background: red;
  animation: animation 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes animation {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0vw);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(100vw - 5em));
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```